# How to avoid claims transformation for certain requests in Asp.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, claims-based-identity, identityserver4, claims

At the API level, I have some identity claims coming from Identity-Server for authorizing the current user and I could use some for first level of authorization. But in a next step, for additional permissions checks, these claims are not enough, I'll have to retrieve more data from database.

My idea was to create a custom `ClaimsPrincipal` where I attach all the permissions from database, but I don't want to call database more than once per request.

So, I thought of having my own implementation of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.IClaimsTransformer` which I added to the pipeline like so:

```
app.UseClaimsTransformation(new ClaimsTransformationOptions() 
{
   Transformer = new MyClaimsTransformer() 
});
```

and my current transformation method:

```
public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsTransformationContext context)
{
    if (context.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var principal = new MyClaimsPrincipal(context.Principal);
        principal.Permissions = /* load from db */;
        return Task.FromResult<ClaimsPrincipal>(principal);
     }
     return Task.FromResult(context.Principal);
}
```

I already noticed that claims transformation method is called every time, with each request. So, I would like to have control over it, to avoid calling the database when there is no authenticated user or no authorization required (case of `AllowAnonymous` attribute) and when there is no need for extra permissions check (ideally).

I feel that the claims transformation should be bound to Identity Server's authorization or something, but no idea how.

Any thoughts on this? Thank you!

**Edit** I found [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/372) that I could hook the claims transformation to `OnTokenValidated` part of `JwtBearerEvents` from `IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation`. Unfortunately, there is another unknown middleware overwriting `MyClaimsPrincipal`. I am puzzled on how this works..

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following check in your ClaimsTransformer to test for anonymous access.

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

private bool IsAnonymousAccessAllowed => UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal(
    HttpContext.Current.Request.Path, 
    AnonymousClaimsPrincipal, 
    HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestType
);
```

with `AnonymousClaimsPrincipal` as

```
ClaimsPrincipal AnonymousClaimsPrincipal => new ClaimsPrincipal(
    (IIdentity) new ClaimsIdentity(
        (IEnumerable<Claim>) new List<Claim>() {
             new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name", "")
        }
    )
);
```

Change the logic in the ClaimsTransformer to skip transformation for anonymous access:

```
if (!IsAnonymousAccessAllowed && context.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { /* ... */ }
```

(This code is from a MVC5 project, I hope it also works in .net core.)

Comment: This is useful.. But I actually found the best place to hook the claims transformation to (see edit).. Although I cannot create my own `ClaimsPrincipal` there, I am thinking to create my own `ClaimsIdentity` to attach the extra data to

Comment: @Learner you can easily add an extensionmethod to ClaimsPrincipal or ClaimsIdentity instead of providing your own Identity class

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl But I wanted to attach a complete object, not only extra claims, so I managed to create my own identity, add it to the `Identities` and then I performed checks against this object in the authorization handlers